# How to set restriction on XSD for id attributes

Tags: android, xml, xsd

If I wanted to define an XSD file for:

```
<state id="1" name="S1">
<state id="2" name="S2">
<state id="3" name="S3">

<transition fromState="1" toState="2">
```

How can I restrict, in the XSD file, the attributes `fromState` and `toState` to get only values that were declared on the `state` elements `id`?

The XSD definition does not seem to have such feature, but take Android XML layouts, somehow the Eclipse Android XML editor knows which ids to put in the content assisted list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to use unique/key/keyref constructs. Considering this modified XML (to add a document element):

```
<Document>
    <state id="1" name="S1"/>
    <state id="2" name="S2"/>
    <state id="3" name="S3"/>

    <transition fromState="1" toState="2"/>
</Document>
```

[image]

This XSD does exactly what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Document">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="state">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="required"/>
                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="transition">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:attribute name="fromState" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="required"/>
                        <xsd:attribute name="toState" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="required"/>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:key name="PKStates">
            <xsd:selector xpath="state"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xsd:key>
        <xsd:keyref name="FKTransitionToStatesFrom"  refer="PKStates">
            <xsd:selector xpath="transition"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="@fromState"/>
        </xsd:keyref>
        <xsd:keyref name="FKTransitionToStatesTo" refer="PKStates">
            <xsd:selector xpath="transition"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="@toState"/>
        </xsd:keyref>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

[image]

If you take a look at the diagrams, you can more easily visualize how selectors work. If you decide to use this and if your XSD has a target namespace and if you qualify your elements and/or attributes, make sure that you declare a prefix for the targetNamespace and use that prefix in your XPath.

In general, not many tools though know how use this information (key/keyref) to build content assisted lists to facilitate XML editing based on the associated XSD. Usually editors with a specialized nature would do that, based on hardwired implementations rather than inference from XSD only.

Comment: Cool tool you use for XSD, What is it? does it generate XSD automatically?. Thanks for the answer. Additionally, let me tell you I learned new stuff I did not even ask from your answer.

Comment: By the way, I use Eclipse. When I created the XSD file with your answer, I got 3 errors for @id, @fromState, @toState xsd:field. `Error: No resource type specified (at 'xpath' with value '@fromState')`. ::: Created a test XML file with XMLSchema-instance using the xsd and the validate works OK, even with the 3 errors I mentioned. ::: Would you know anything about it? I think I will open a new question with this.

Comment: The schema I've posted is valid - tested it with the latest .NET and Xerces (Java). Validation errors for invalid content would look: `Error occurred while loading [], line 7 position 3
The key sequence '13' in Keyref fails to refer to some key.
...:\some.xml is XSD 1.0 invalid.
Error while loading [], line 7 position 12
cvc-identity-constraint.4.3: Key 'FKTransitionToStatesFrom' with value '13' not found for identity constraint of element 'Document'.
...:\some.xml is XSD 1.0 invalid.`

Comment: @ilomambo, see above comment and the answer to your other question.